# Python: Randomly split a data frame in half and assign value in a new column

Tags: python, dataframe, random, split

I have a list of Ids (device Ids) in a DataFrame.
I want to assign randomly A or B to each one of these devices (split them into two halfs):

Assume we have a DataFrame named `devices` with a column `"DeviceId"` and 9364957 rows.

**Option 1:**

```
def coin():
    p = 0.5
    
    r = np.random.random()
    return 'B' if r > p else 'A'


devices['Experiment'] = pd.DataFrame( [coin() for i in range(devices.shape[0])])

g = devices.groupby(['Experiment']).agg(['count'])
print(g.head(10))
```

Output :

> Experiment
> A           4681923
>
> B           4683034

there are 1,111 entries more in `A` than in `B`!

**Option 2: (i got stuck :()**

```
A = devices.sample(frac=0.5, replace=False)
print('\tselect as A: ', A.shape[0])
```

> select as A:  4682478

in a simple calculation this is much better split because this way B will get 4682479 (the delta between both is exactly 1)

But how can i proceed from here?

My target is to get an updated DataFrame `devices` with two columns:
`DeviceId` , `Experiment` (which is either `"A"` or `"B"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to create a new column for experiments. Here is one method that builds upon the `sample()` function you were using:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some sample data
devices = pd.DataFrame({'DeviceId': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]})

# initialize experiment column to 'A'
devices['Experiment'] = 'A'

# use the index of a sampling to change ~50% of the labels to 'B'
devices.loc[devices.sample(frac=0.5, replace=False).index,'Experiment'] = 'B'
```

In my example, I got the following counts:

```
>>> devices.groupby('Experiment').count()

Experiment  DeviceId
A           5
B           6
```

Or, if you wanted to use your `coin()` function - you could try `apply()` (though this is probably slower):

```
devices['Experiment'] = devices.apply(lambda x: coin(), axis=1)
```

As an aside, having 1,111 more entries in `B` than `A` is not a bug- it's a consequence of generating (psuedo) random numbers. Looking at those numbers as a percentage of your populations:

```
A=0.49994068312326473
B=0.5000593168767353
```

Which is *very* close to the 50/50 split you wanted. The more samples you draw, the closer you'll approach 50/50 (theoretically).